# How to update my component based on dom in React

Tags: reactjs, dom, state

I am using React and clicking on a button. When I click that button something shows up on the page and therefore the dom gets updated with that as well.

I am trying to use `useEffect` to check if the dom updated with that content I have a `div` with an `id` of `whatever`.

I am doing something like...

```
const [color, setColor] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
    const isVisible = document.getElementById('whatever');

    if (isVisible) {
      setColor('blue');
    } else {
      setColor('');
    }
}, [isVisible])
```

My plan is that if isVisible is true then I will update the color to `blue` in this case and blue will be the background of my page.

I want to do this specifically by trying to access the dom in this way or some other way but definitely by trying to access the dom and I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: Since you are already using React `useEffect` hook, I would recommend also using `useRef` hook to get the DOM element instead of `document.getElementById` and `useState` hook to set state and use that state in your logic

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will check this out.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid that approach. You should avoid accessing DOM elements on SPAs as best you can.

React best practice would set a state like `isWhateverVisible` to `true` once button click. That state would be used to conditionally render `whatever` like `{isWhateverVisible && <div>whatever to show on click</div>}` .

Then, pass the state variable down as prop `isWhateverVisible` and use at your component. you can actually remove `useEffect` in that way, and apply the props directly at your component to conditionally paint your page like `<div style={{backgroundColor: props.isWhateverVisible ? 'blue' : '' }}>something</div>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know that this is the accepted way but just wanted to know how to do it by accessing dom elements. Being that I am using Redux it should be very easy to just grab some state from my store to pass into my components. However, still appreciate the help and feedback. Thanks!